# Is it considered bad practice to change activities during an AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

I'm making a call to my Firebase Database using the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method to read values from the database. This method is implemented as an `AsyncTask` according to a few SO posts. Inside this method, I validate the data, and based on the values, `finish()` may be called. I know `AsyncTask` is meant to handle UI elements, but is it meant to handle switching activities?

My concern is that since it is running asynchronously, code outside this method may run first, and if that code outside includes switching activities (currently it does not, but it may be subject to change), then it may crash my app when it tries to call `finish()` inside `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` after.

What is the best way to handle activity switching while using `AsyncTasks`?

Answer (score 0):

You could initiate Async Task inside presenter and presenter will handle the lifecycle of Activity/Fragment. This is **MVP** architecture

If activity/fragment is destroyed, async task will run on background. So during onPostExecute, it will crash. So the best practice is saving state of activity/fragment inside presenter and presenter will provide callback to activity to switch to new activity if activity is live.

Let me show an example

```
public interface BaseFirstActivity {
void switchActivity();
}

public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseFirstActivity {
FirstActivityPresenter firstActivityPresenter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    firstActivityPresenter = new FirstAcitivtyPresenterImpl(this);
    firstActivityPresenter.fetchDB();
}

@Override
public void switchActivity() {
    // do switching
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    firstActivityPresenter.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}
}


public interface FirstActivityPresenter  {
void onDestroy();
void fetchDB();
 }

public class FirstAcitivtyPresenterImpl implements FirstActivityPresenter {
private BaseFirstActivity baseFirstActivity;

public FirstAcitivtyPresenterImpl(BaseFirstActivity baseFirstActivity) {
    this.baseFirstActivity = baseFirstActivity;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    baseFirstActivity = null;
}

@Override
public void fetchDB() {
    //do asyntask and after fetching
    if (baseFirstActivity != null)
        baseFirstActivity.switchActivity();
}
}
```

You could use **onStop** and **onResume** to detach and attach presenter. Also you can use same call back mechanism for **AsynTask** as seperate class